# ons-listにエフェクトをかけたい

Tags: monaca

スクロール時の動きが地味なのでhttp://lab.hakim.se/scroll-effects/のような動きをつけたいのですが、あまりに構造が違いすぎて途方に暮れているのですが、これに似た動きをする別のおすすめのjqueryはありますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

`<ons-list>`は単なるCSSのプリセットですので、スタイリングにこだわりたいなら`<ons-list>`をあえて使う必要はありません。普通に`<ul>`と`<li>`でマークアップして、CSSをいくらか書いてstroll.jsを使われてはどうでしょうか。

以下はAngularでの使用例です。

```js
ons.bootstrap().controller('appController', function($scope, $timeout){
  $timeout(function(){
    stroll.bind('.stroll');
  });

  $scope.range = function(min, max, step){
    step = step || 1;
    var input = [];
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i += step) input.push(i);
    return input;
  };
});
```

```css
/**
 * Demo page styles, all list scroll effects styles are in sctroll.css
 */
html, body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

body {
 background: #323232;
 font-family: 'Lato', Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #eee;
 margin-bottom: 40px;
 line-height: 1;
}
article {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 20px;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 16px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

/**
 * List used for the demo page
 */
ul {
 position: relative;
 width: 230px;
 height: 480px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 list-style: none;

 -webkit-perspective: 400px;
    -moz-perspective: 400px;
     -ms-perspective: 400px;
      -o-perspective: 400px;
         perspective: 400px;
}
 ul li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 16px;
  background: #eee;
  color: #252525;
  font-size: 18px;
  z-index: 2;

  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
     -moz-transform: translateZ(0px);
      -ms-transform: translateZ(0px);
       -o-transform: translateZ(0px);
          transform: translateZ(0px);
 }
 ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #fff;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/hakimel/stroll.js/master/css/stroll.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.6/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/hakimel/stroll.js/master/js/stroll.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="appController">
  <article>
    <h2>Grow</h2>
    <ul class="grow stroll"><li ng-repeat="i in range(1, 100)">Item{{i}}</li></ul>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h2>Cards</h2>
    <ul class="cards stroll"><li ng-repeat="i in range(1, 100)">Item{{i}}</li></ul>
  </article>
</body>
```

-